# Edit a django login form

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication

I am running an example django app from this library, [here is](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/example) the whole code.

I would like to add the login part of this app, i want to add more fields to the login view but i really don't understand how to do that, because the app does not have it's own view, but it's just calling the module's own login view. But what if i would like to use this library for my own project? Would i be forced to use their login view? How can i edit it?

Here is the login view that the example is calling to handle authentication:

**[core.py](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/views/core.py)**

```
@class_view_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
@class_view_decorator(never_cache)
class LoginView(IdempotentSessionWizardView):
    """
    View for handling the login process, including OTP verification.
    The login process is composed like a wizard. The first step asks for the
    user's credentials. If the credentials are correct, the wizard proceeds to
    the OTP verification step. If the user has a default OTP device configured,
    that device is asked to generate a token (send sms / call phone) and the
    user is asked to provide the generated token. The backup devices are also
    listed, allowing the user to select a backup device for verification.
    """
    template_name = 'two_factor/core/login.html'
    form_list = (
        ('auth', AuthenticationForm),
        ('token', AuthenticationTokenForm),
        ('backup', BackupTokenForm),
    )
    idempotent_dict = {
        'token': False,
        'backup': False,
    }

    def has_token_step(self):
        return default_device(self.get_user())

    def has_backup_step(self):
        return default_device(self.get_user()) and \
            'token' not in self.storage.validated_step_data

    condition_dict = {
        'token': has_token_step,
        'backup': has_backup_step,
    }
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.user_cache = None
        self.device_cache = None

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The user can select a particular device to challenge, being the backup
        devices added to the account.
        """
        # Generating a challenge doesn't require to validate the form.
        if 'challenge_device' in self.request.POST:
            return self.render_goto_step('token')

        return super(LoginView, self).post(*args, **kwargs)

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        """
        Login the user and redirect to the desired page.
        """
        login(self.request, self.get_user())

        redirect_to = self.request.POST.get(
            self.redirect_field_name,
            self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')
        )

        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, allowed_hosts=[self.request.get_host()]):
            redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        device = getattr(self.get_user(), 'otp_device', None)
        if device:
            signals.user_verified.send(sender=__name__, request=self.request,
                                       user=self.get_user(), device=device)
        return redirect(redirect_to)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        """
        AuthenticationTokenForm requires the user kwarg.
        """
        if step == 'auth':
            return {
                'request': self.request
            }
        if step in ('token', 'backup'):
            return {
                'user': self.get_user(),
                'initial_device': self.get_device(step),
            }
        return {}

    def get_device(self, step=None):
        """
        Returns the OTP device selected by the user, or his default device.
        """
        if not self.device_cache:
            challenge_device_id = self.request.POST.get('challenge_device', None)
            if challenge_device_id:
                for device in backup_phones(self.get_user()):
                    if device.persistent_id == challenge_device_id:
                        self.device_cache = device
                        break
            if step == 'backup':
                try:
                    self.device_cache = self.get_user().staticdevice_set.get(name='backup')
                except StaticDevice.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
            if not self.device_cache:
                self.device_cache = default_device(self.get_user())
        return self.device_cache

    def render(self, form=None, **kwargs):
        """
        If the user selected a device, ask the device to generate a challenge;
        either making a phone call or sending a text message.
        """
        if self.steps.current == 'token':
            self.get_device().generate_challenge()
        return super(LoginView, self).render(form, **kwargs)

    def get_user(self):
        """
        Returns the user authenticated by the AuthenticationForm. Returns False
        if not a valid user; see also issue #65.
        """
        if not self.user_cache:
            form_obj = self.get_form(step='auth',
                                     data=self.storage.get_step_data('auth'))
            self.user_cache = form_obj.is_valid() and form_obj.user_cache
        return self.user_cache

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        """
        Adds user's default and backup OTP devices to the context.
        """
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'token':
            context['device'] = self.get_device()
            context['other_devices'] = [
                phone for phone in backup_phones(self.get_user())
                if phone != self.get_device()]
            try:
                context['backup_tokens'] = self.get_user().staticdevice_set\
                    .get(name='backup').token_set.count()
            except StaticDevice.DoesNotExist:
                context['backup_tokens'] = 0

        if getattr(settings, 'LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL', None):
            context['cancel_url'] = resolve_url(settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL)
        elif getattr(settings, 'LOGOUT_URL', None):
            warnings.warn(
                "LOGOUT_URL has been replaced by LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL, please "
                "review the URL and update your settings.",
                DeprecationWarning)
            context['cancel_url'] = resolve_url(settings.LOGOUT_URL)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this package in one of my projects and many complicated scenarios can come up with it. There can be a lot of ways you can customize this view. As you mentioned, you need extra fields in login form, here is one method you can use if you just want extra fields in login form.

**Step 1 Create your own login form with extra fields**

You can create your own login form, inherit from django's builtin one or inherit from the form they are using for login. Add extra fields in it.

```
class YourLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    pass
    # your extra fields and functionality here
```

**Step 2 Inherit from login view from package and use your form**

You have to create a login view inherited from package's builtin login view and add your login form along with other ones like this

```
from TWO_FACTOR_AUTU import LoginView

class YourLoginView(LoginView):
    form_list = (
        ('auth', YourLoginForm),
        ('token', AuthenticationTokenForm),
        ('backup', BackupTokenForm),
    )
```

Use this view with appropriate routing for handling authentication.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry for the noob questions but i'm fairly new to Django. Right now i already have a login form created by me, but the problem is that i don't know how to integrate the whole 2fa part into that one, that's why i asked this question. Would it be more difficult to integrate 2fa into my own login view or would it be better to add extra fields to their own view? And can you tell me where should i put those 2 pieces of code you mentioned? In my project? And in which files? Again, i'm sorry but i'm new to this. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I suggest you to use their authentication view with your form rather than using your  view with their two factor functionality. It would be relatively easy. You can put this code in any of your application , form in `forms.py` and view in `views.py`. Just take care of login functionality in form. It must should handle authentication and invalidate itself if username and password is wrong.

Comment: Ok! So the second block of code should go into my own login view, while the first one on forms.py? Thanks!